# initialising multiple empty lists

Tags: c#

Simple syntactic c# question is this.

Given this code:

```
List<string> Columns = new List<string>();
List<string> Parameters = new List<string>();
List<string> Values = new List<string>();
```

It can be reduced to:

```
List<string> Columns = new List<string>(), Parameters = new List<string>(), Values = new List<string>();
```

But can I get it shorter still, since they're all being initialised to an empty list?

Thank you all!

Comment: Don't go for *shortest* code. Go for *clearest* code.

Comment: So why do you want it, because you have repetitive lines of code or because you think that these lists are redundant? What are you going to do with them?

Comment: @Adrian Hand - Is there any specific reason for needing this code to be as short as possible?

Comment: this is a bad idea.  It reduces readability at the cost of what a few hundred characters?  Code is to be written for humans not machines.

Comment: Second one won't compile I think..

Comment: I would Suggest naming your `Variables such as Columns, Parameters, Values` as lower case as well since these can be seen as reserved words and or to lower the confusion.. just a suggestion

Comment: @SonerGönül it's a pity, but it will compile.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2068421/1952879

Comment: thank you all for your suggestions; I suppose the question was not asked because I felt that the code above could be improved upon by being changed - rather I wanted to be more syntactically knowledgeable. I thank you all - Jon Skeet especially!

Comment: Personally of the two I would go for the reduced version, but I would put each new variable on its own line to increase readability.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I can recommend to use `var` keyword if these variables are not class fields, because types are know from usage. It really makes no sense to flat declaration of three variables.

```
var Columns = new List<string>();
var Parameters = new List<string>();
var Values = new List<string>();
```

Yes, you can do things, like declaring multiple local variables in one line and then initializing them in one line. But please, **avoid** declaring multiple variables in one line - it makes code much readable.

Comment: `Columns = Parameters = Values = new List<string>();` is not what the asker wants.  This would have all three variables referencing the same `List<string>` object.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. You can use lambda as Tim showed, but I will just remove multiple declaration - it's too nasty

Answer (score 5):

Purely as a point of trivia/code golf:

```
Func<List<string>> n = () => new List<string>();
List<string> a = n(), b = n(), c = n(), d = n(), e = n(), f = n();
```

But it would be ridiculous to use this in place of the much clearer constructs available. It *might* have value if the initialization was more complex, and the code was properly named and spaced.

```
Func<List<string>> setupFoo = () => {
    return new List<string>() { 1, 2, 3 };
};

var option1 = setupFoo();
var option2 = setupFoo();
var option3 = setupFoo();
```

Answer (score 3):

IEnumerable is the most basic interface for collections. 
Using this, you can instantiate any type of collection dynamically.

For empty lists, use.

```
Enumerable.Empty<TYPE>();
```

In your example...

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
...
IEnumerable<string> Columns = Enumerable.Empty<string>();
IEnumerable<string> Parameters = Enumerable.Empty<string>();
IEnumerable<string> Values = Enumerable.Empty<string>();
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not a great practice, but if you're initializing string lists a lot within a single .cs file, you can add an alias for the class with the file's other `using` statements:

```
using StringList = List<string>;
```

And then the code to declare and initialize them would be:

```
StringList Columns = new StringList(), 
           Parameters = new StringList(), 
           Values = new StringList();
```

Comment: While this is possible, I __highly recommend against it__. If I was reading code that had `new StringList()` I would assume that is some kind of class. When I saw it was simply a `using` alias I would be rather disappointed and promptly Ctrl+H to replace. Code like that will just confuse other developers, including yourself if you ever take a break from the project and come back later.

Comment: Consider that we have a `Dictionary<String, KeyValuePair<Guid,List<KeyValuePair<String, List<MyClass>>>>>`, I would want to be able to shorten that using a using ;).

Answer (score 2):

You can't shorten anymore.

You *could* use some kind of "empty list factory":

```
public static List<string> EmptySList()
{
    return EmptyList<string>();
}

public static List<T> EmptyList<T>()
{
    return new List<T>();
}

...

List<string> Columns = EmptySList(), Parameters = EmptySList(), Values = EmptySList();
```

Honestly, you probably don't want to shorten your code. Just write something readable and maintainable:

```
var columns = new List<string>();
var parameters = new List<string>();
var values = new List<string>();
```